# AppleScript is producing json instead of string

Tags: applescript

My AppleScript is producing JSON instead of a plain string. Here's the code. 
 
`set lok to input2 & "/Contents/"`
input2 is a variable that becomes a string. I get this error: 
Can’t make {"[whatever input2 was]", "/Contents/"} into type string. 
I don't understand what is going on. I did not call anything. When I call input2 by itself, it gives me it in plain text. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not JSON (obviously because it isn't JS), it's an AppleScript list that when you execute & it adds another object to the list. To return text, coerce it "as text" like so:

```
set lok to (input2 as text) & "/Contents/"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a json, it's an AppleScript list.
The & operator adds another object to the list. If you want the list as text you need to coerce it "as text" like so

```
set lok to (input2 & "/Contents/") as text
```

Comment: Don’t do that: coercing a list to text produces different results depending on text item delimiters. Use: `set lok to (input2 as text) & "/Contents/"`. TBH I suspect OP’s item 2 is a file specifier, e.g. `POSIX file "…"`, in which case use `(posix path of input2)` to convert it to a POSIX path string.

Comment: If it's a string delivered and delimiers are untouched- I don't see an issue. why make it more complicated for a beginner than necesaary

Comment: Nonsense, it’s the exact same length of code using the exact same operators. The only difference is your version also adds a nasty hidden gotcha which is going bite the user sooner or later—the very definition of making it more complicated than necessary. There are ways to write code that is safe and robust, and ways to write code that is a flaky dangerous horror. Stack Overflow is meant for the former; for the latter try [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: @foo @ Pat_Morita pls don't argue even tho I used foo's answer.